# V 8.2 (Обычные формы) элементы формы

Tags: 1с

Господа, подскажите в чем причина.
V 8.2 (Обычные формы)
Пытаюсь подредактировать обработку МенеджерКонтактов (добавить еще один отбор по Состояниям Событий).

Есть 2 элемента Поле ввода с составным типом значения (СписокЗначений, ПеречислениеСсылка.<...>)
У стандартного эл. ЗначениеОтбораВидОперации есть "форма выбора" у добавленного нет.
Уже все просмотрела логики не вижу.
[image: Тут есть поле формы выбора]

[image: а тут нету]

Answer (score 0):

У второго элемента нет формы выбора потому что вы использовали составной тип значения.
Для перечисления форма выбора есть, но **для списка значений нет**, дело в этом.